# How do I install wine 7.0 on Ubuntu 23.04 or resolve 'a bitmap could not be found or bitmap load failed' error?

Tags: upgrade, wine, 23.04

I upgraded to **Ubuntu 23.04** and was testing **'Family Tree Maker 16' (FTM)** and had problems.  Initially just iKernel.exe was an issue.  I resolved this by using a new **WINEPREFIX**.  Now I have the error **'a bitmap could not be found or bitmap load failed'**.  Does anyone know how to solve this or how to replace wine 8.0 with wine 7.0?

This used to work on **Ubuntu 22.10** and prior versions back as far as **Ubuntu 14.04**.  The main difference between Ubuntu 22.10 and Ubuntu 23.04 affecting FTM was the wine version.  It jumped from 7.0 to 8.0.  On the file system this meant FTM instead of being located in drive_c/Program Files now was located on drive_c/Program Files (x86).

On **Ubuntu 23.04** I've tried adding **corefonts** with winetricks and then tried **winehq-stable 8.0.1** which added many 32bit libraries that were missing and also tried **wine 8.7**. libfreetype6-dev:i386 had to be added. Building from source was successful but generated same problem with **FTM** app.  I was hopeful of an improvement because **FTM's** application main menu appeared.  The install process generates no issues.  This version of **FTM** uses Ole2 for file format.  Potentially I removed un-needed Ubuntu 32bit system files too quickly in the upgrade or that **FTM** is failing to open some default FTW file.  I had access to a vanilla system with **Ubuntu 22.10**, did `sudo apt-get install wine`, **wine 7.0**, installed **FTM** and **FTM** worked.

On the **Ubuntu 23.04** I have now downloaded the source code used to build **wine-7.0** from [ubuntu archive for wine] [1](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/) and had to use `autconf` as no `configure` was archived plus download `config.guess` and `config.sub`.  Also, numerous .ico were missing, some test.avi, some .c files, some .nls files, and some .h files.  I will update whether this **wine-7.0** works on **Ubuntu 23.04**.  This process is more involved than I thought, having to `./configure --without-capi`.  I tried **winehq** version **wine-7.0.1** from source and **FTM** didn't work which was why I was using the Ubuntu archive as on **Ubuntu 22.10** **FTM** worked with the regular `sudo apt-get install wine`.